# Aggregate multiple vars on different groupings in one Proc SQL query

Tags: sas, proc

I need to aggregate about ten different vars on different groupings using Proc SQL;
Is there a way to achieve SUM () OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause) in one sql query with different partition by clauses.

I've made an example here

```
data have;
infile cards;
input a b c d e f;
cards;
1 2 3 4 5
2 2 4 5 6
1 4 3 4 7
3 4 4 5 8
;
run;
proc sql;
create table want as
select *,
sum a over partiton by (b,c) as a1,
sum b over partiton by (c,d) as b1
sum c over partiton by (d,e) as c1
sum d over partiton by (a,c) as d1
from have
;
quit;
```

I don't want to wirte multiple sql queries and grouping on different vars and calculating one var in each step.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you really want to treat all of the variables as both class variables and analysis variables?  If not can you make a more realistic example?

Answer (score 0):

`Proc SQL` does not implement windowing functions and thus partition syntax therein as found in other SQL implementations.  You can only do `partition by` with passthrough SQL to a connection that allows such syntax.

You could perform such a computation in DATA step using hashes.

```
data have;
infile cards;
input a b c d e ;
cards;
1 2 3 4 5
2 2 4 5 6
1 4 3 4 7
3 4 4 5 8
;
run;

data want;
  if 0 then set have;

  length a1 b1 c1 d1 8;

  declare hash a1s();
  a1s.defineKey('b', 'c');
  a1s.defineData('a1');
  a1s.defineDone();

  declare hash b1s();
  b1s.defineKey('c', 'd');
  b1s.defineData('b1');
  b1s.defineDone();

  declare hash c1s();
  c1s.defineKey('d', 'e');
  c1s.defineData('c1');
  c1s.defineDone();

  declare hash d1s();
  d1s.defineKey('a', 'c');
  d1s.defineData('d1');
  d1s.defineDone();

  do while (not end);
    set have end=end;
    if a1s.find() = 0 then a1+a; else a1=a;  a1s.replace();
    if b1s.find() = 0 then b1+b; else b1=b;  b1s.replace();
    if c1s.find() = 0 then c1+c; else c1=c;  c1s.replace();
    if d1s.find() = 0 then d1+d; else d1=d;  d1s.replace();
  end;

  do while (not last);
    set have end=last;
    a1s.find();
    b1s.find();
    c1s.find();
    d1s.find();
    output;
  end;

  format _numeric_ 4.;

  stop;
run;
```